# How to convert CMSampleBufferRef(audio +video) to a video file(.mp4 or .mov) using AVAssetWriter every 10 seconds in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am using AVFoundation's `AVCaptureSession` to capture video for live streaming ( to send to the server using `RTMP protocol`).

The callback delegate methods of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` and `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` returns the `CMSampleBufferRef` in  the following method :

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutputdidOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBufferfromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

As per the contents of this link , I can convert this buffer content to a file using [**THIS LINK**](https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/capturing-video/#avcapturedataoutput-and-avassetwriter).

like

```
NSURL *url = …;
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:url fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:nil];
AVAssetWriterInput *videoInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput alloc] initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:nil];
videoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
AVAssetWriterInput *audioInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput alloc] initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio outputSettings:nil];
audioInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
if ([assetWriter canAddInput:videoInput]) {
    [assetWriter addInput:videoInput];
}
if ([assetWriter canAddInput:audioInput]) {
    [assetWriter addInput:audioInput];
}
```

But I am not getting the exact logic involved in this file conversion. The `didOutputSampleBuffer`
is a frame by frame captured (uncompressed )raw data and I want to convert these frames into a single file at certain interval.like say at each 10 seconds or so.And I want to send this file to the server.

Can someone give a brief idea about how `AVAssetWriter` works?or correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution for this?

Comment: Nop. I couldn't do it.